# Pass textbox input to perl script on server

Tags: perl, cgi

Sorry in advance for a potentially dumb newbie question, but here goes.

I am learning web app programming and I would like to have an input textbox on my webpage where the user enters some text.  Then I capture that text and pass to a perl script which generates some output.  I then take this text output and pass it back to the webpage.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this.

Can be a really simple example, where the user inputs some text.  I take the text and pass to a perl script which turns everything to uppercase - uc() - and then passes back to the webpage.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your html body:

```
<FORM ACTION="/cgi-bin/results.pl">
<P>Enter a value: <INPUT NAME="value">
<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Next">
</FORM>
```

In your results.pl:

```
use CGI qw(:standard); 
my $value = uc(param('value'));
print header;
print start_html;
print p($value);
print end_html;
```

Comment: hmmm.. somehow i get 500 internal server error when running this. not sure what i am doing wrong.  i checked that i have cgi.pm so that's not issue.

Comment: @racket99 Usually this means your script isn't compiling. What do you get when you run it from the command line? `./results.pl`

Comment: actually i didn't make it executable.  my bad.  it works now.

Answer (score 0):

`use`[`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI)`;`

```
my $q = CGI->new;
my $text_box_value = $q->param( 'my_text_box_name' );
```

This is a decent CGI tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm . Or there's this http://www.cgi101.com/book/ or this http://www.lies.com/begperl/ or this http://websitehelpers.com/perl/ all found here: http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+CGI+tutorial

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the text from the webpage to this script?

Answer (score 0):

The page needs to contain a [form](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/20-html-forms-the-basics/). The action attribute of the form needs to point to a URL that your webserver will process with the Perl program. The simplist way to achieve this is using [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI), a more modern approach uses [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/). Most Perl form processing libraries use a [similar interface to CGI.pm's](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#FETCHING_THE_VALUE_OR_VALUES_OF_A_SINGLE_NAMED_PARAMETER%3a)